# Odds on dice with 5-sided die

Tags: probability, odds

If a die with only 5 sides was tossed 5 times,

1. Would the odds of a "5" coming up 5 times in succession be .2 to the fifth power or .00032?
2. Would the odds of any one number coming up 5 times be .00032 x 5 or .0016?
3. What would be the odds of all the numbers "1" through "5" coming up in any order such as ("2", "5", "1", "4", "3")?

Comment: Is this a question from a course or textbook? If so, please add the `[self-study]`
tag & read its [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: Note that [odds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odds#Statistical_usage) are different from probability, and you seem actually asking about probability there.

Comment: I'd say that probability is 0 since 5-sided die is impossible ;)

Answer (score 2):

> If a die with only 5 sides was tossed 5 times would the odds of a 5 coming up 5 times in succession be .2 to the fifth power or .00032?

Correct* the probability is $(\frac15)^5$.

*(assuming you specify the event prior to observing it rather than seeing it and then after the fact going "*whoah, what are the chances???*")

> Would the odds of any one number coming up 5 times be .00032 x 5 or .0016?

Yes.

> What would be the odds of all the numbers 1 through 5 coming up in any order such as 2,5,1,4,3?

Here's how to think about that problem:

1. How many possibilities are there for the first number in the sequence?
2. Given the first number (say "2"), how many possible values are there for the second number, which is different from the first?
3. Given the first two numbers (e.g. "2", "5"), how many possible values are there for the third number, which is different from the first two?

and so on until you have done all five numbers. That's the number of ways of getting 5 different outcomes in 5 tosses.

You then divide by the total number of ways there are of the 5 tosses coming up (which you already seem to have figured out is $5^5$).

(It's a number somewhere  between 3 and 4%)